# Replace text in HTML body

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to replace text in the body of a template already created in Outlook 2010.  The purpose of this is so that users can update the contact which the email is being sent to fairly easily.

```
Sub NewUserEmail()

Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strContact As String
Dim strCompanyName As String
Dim strHTML As String

Set myItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate( _
      "C:\Users\jim.reagan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\NewUserEmail.oft")
    strHTML = myItem.HTMLBody
    strContact = InputBox("What is the Contact's name?")
    myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "%<Contact>%", strContact)

myItem.Display
End Sub
```

The template opens up for review but no replacements have been made to the body of the email.  If I use myItem.Body the replacement works but then I lose my formatting of my email.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the HTMLBody actually contains "%%"?

Comment: Its part of the string that I put in body of the email.  Something used from boilerplate template.

Comment: Ok, but can you output (MsgBox?) the contents of the HTMLBody property before and after setting the property?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko - thank you very much.  I ran into this same issue and your idea helped point me in the right direction (by using a write-host versus MsgBox).  But I found that the process was inserting additional code into the template HTMLbody that was separating the phrase that I was trying to "replacing".  I tried using % and ! and others, but HTML kept separating them from the phrase itself.  The actual HTML code being produced was "</span>!<span class=SpellE>" (w/o quotes) when I used the exclamation point.  So I removed all "special" characters and used letters only. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to tag or flag an answer for this but here is the code that I got to work from the editing provided by Tim Williams, thank you for your help with this:

```
Sub NewUserEmail()

    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strContact As String
    Dim strCompanyName As String
    Dim strHTML As String


    Set myItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\file location\file.oft")
    strHTML = myItem.HTMLBody
    strContact = InputBox("What is the Contact's name?")
    myItem.HTMLBody = Replace(myItem.HTMLBody, "%CONTACT%", strContact)

    myItem.Display

End Sub
```