# Outlook MailItem HTMLBody Replace() not working - brand new be gentle

Tags: vba, replace, outlook, mailitem

Okay here is the updated version... still not working though

```
        NextHTMLBody = nextMessage.HTMLBody
        NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%Customer_Name%", bBodyName)
        NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%##%", formPage.Controls("LoanNumber1").Value)

        With nextMessage
            .HTMLBody = NextHTMLBody
            .Subject = subjEmail
            .To = sendTo
            .Send
        End With
```

-------------and here it works.. not sure what I did differently

```
        'Set body
        NextHTMLBody = nextMessage.HTMLBody
        NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%Customer_Name%", bBodyName)
        NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%##%", formPage.Controls("LoanNumber1").Value)

        With nextMessage
            .HTMLBody = NextHTMLBody
            '.Body = NextHTMLBody
            .Subject = subjEmail
            .To = sendTo
            '.Send
            .Display
        End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace should work OK here:

```
If InStr(nextMessage.HTMLBody, "%Customer_Name%") <> 0 Then
    NextHTMLBody = Replace(nextMessage.Body, "%Customer_Name%", bBodyName)
End If
```

But in the next block you're discarding the replacement you performed above by going back to `nextMessage.HTMLBody` instead of continuing with `NextHTMLBody`. You're also switching to `HTMLBody` from `Body`: not sure if there's a reson for that.

```
If InStr(nextMessage.HTMLBody, "%##%") <> 0 Then

    NextHTMLBody = Replace(nextMessage.HTMLBody, "%##%", _
                             formPage.Controls("LoanNumber1").Value)
End If
```

Best bet is something more like this (you don't really need the If-Then here):

```
NextHTMLBody = nextMessage.HTMLBody

NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%Customer_Name%", bBodyName)

NextHTMLBody = Replace(NextHTMLBody, "%##%", _
                             formPage.Controls("LoanNumber1").Value)
```

Comment: This looks great! sometimes it's just a second set of eyes. Thanks a bunch Tim, i'll try it in the AM and post up the results. Made my evening!

Comment: Tim, if I switch the mail property to .body it works. the weird thing is when I run this REPLACE() function in VBS it works on .HTMLBody

Comment: Just ran into this myself (for anyone else seeing this post, hope this helps).  What was happening is that when I used "special" characters in my field to replace, it didn't work.  Turns out that HTMLbody is changing something like "!NAME" into "</span>!<span class=SpellE>NAME" (without all the quotes).  So when I try to replace "!NAME" using PS, it can't find it (so it can't replace it).  So don't use special characters or spaces.  Credit goes to this post at SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154063/replace-text-in-html-body