Is it possible to combine multiple oft templates into one?
I'm currently attempting to put together a form in Access that will piece together an email.
As of right now the form works but it loads up one template file that I'm unable to make changes to via HTMLBody.Replace due to system security settings. Once the template loads, the user has to go through the body and delete the parts that are not applicable to the current situation.
If possible, I would like to be able to split the template into multiple pieces and plug and play each piece based on the selections of the user.
Is it possible to CreateItemFromTemplate() multiple times and combine their bodies into one item? If not using that method, is it possible to achieve what I'm attempting from another angle?

My guess to first question is no. To the second, build email from scratch.

I don't think you can, but what is wrong with HTMLBody.Replace? What does it have to do with "system security settings"?

AFAIK, HTMLBody.Replace is not even valid code. Use Replace() function -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154063/replace-text-in-html-body. Edit question to post attempted code.
